# Closed subscheme of a projective scheme determined by homogeneous ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

So in Ravi Vakil's notes Ex 8.2C, I have to prove that if $\pi:X\hookrightarrow\text{Proj}\ S_{\cdot}$ is a closed subscheme (here $S_{\cdot}$ is a graded ring finitely generated by elements of degree 1), then there exists a homogeneous ideal $I$ such that $X=\text{Proj}\ S_{\cdot}/I$.

I have gone as far as proving the following:

Suppose $S_\cdot$ is generated by $x_i$'s for $i=0,...,n$. Then by definition of closed subscheme, on $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Proj}\ S_{\cdot}}(D(x_i ))$ we have an ideal $I_i$ of $((S_{\cdot})_{x_{i}})_{0}$. Then I let $J_i$ to be the homogeneous ideal in $S_{\cdot}$ such that

$$ J_{i}=\bigoplus_{d}\{a\in S_d: a/x_{i}^{d}\in I_{i}\}.$$

Then I let $I=\cap J_{i}$. The reason why I arrive at this is as follows and in fact I am not even sure it is correct: that each of the $I_i$ in $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Proj}\ S_{\cdot}}(D(x_i ))$ corresponds to a closed subscheme of $D(x_i )$. Then $X$ is supposed to be the union of these closed subschemes which translates to the intersection of ideals, and hence the result. Surprisingly, I got the correct homogeneous ideal by checking the sources, but I have a problem of proving that this corresponds to the desired $X$. I have searched several sources but it requires using coherent modules and some other techniques which are only proven in the later chapters. Is there a way to prove this using elementary way? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The ideal in the post is the correct one. It suffices to show that the sections of $\widetilde{I\ }$ are the same as those of $\mathcal{I}_X$, the ideal sheaf of $X$ on each open affine $D(x_i)$.

First, we note that $\widetilde{J_i}(D(x_i))=(J_i)_{(x_i)}=\mathcal{I}_{X}(D(x_i))$. So it's enough to show that $I_{(x_i)}=(J_i)_{(x_i)}$ for all $i$. As $I\subset J_i$ implies $I_{(x_i)}\subset (J_i)_{(x_i)}$, it's enough to show that for any $f\in J_i$, we can find $fx_i^e\in J_j$ for all $j\neq i$ for some $e\geq 0$, as then $\frac{fx_i^e}{x_i^{e+\deg f}}=\frac{f}{x_i^{\deg f}}$ and we see the equality $I_{(x_i)}=(J_i)_{(x_i)}$.

Fix $i$. Pick some $f\in S_d$ so that $f\in J_i$. Then on $D(x_j)$ for $j\neq i$, $\frac{f}{x_j^d}=\frac{f}{x_i^d}\cdot\frac{x_i^d}{x_j^d}$ is in $\mathcal{I}_X(D(x_j) \cap D(x_i))$, so after adjustment by a factor of $\frac{x_i^{d_j}}{x_j^{d_j}}$, we have that $\frac{fx_i^{d_j}}{x_j^{d+d_j}}\in (J_j)_{(x_j)}$ and therefore $fx_i^{d_j}\in J_j$. So by picking $e=\max_j(d_j)$, we get that $fx_i^e\in J_j$ for all $j$, and thus $fx_i^e\in I$. This exactly shows what we wanted.

Comment: thank you. i want to understand the first sentence. Is it your claim that in complete generality if $\varphi_X:X\hookrightarrow Z$ and $\varphi_Y:Y\hookrightarrow Z$ are closed subschemes of $Z$ and if $\{U_i \cong Spec R_i\}$ is a cover of $Z$ by open affines, then if for each $i$ we have $ker (R_i\rightarrow ~\mathcal{O}_X(\varphi_X^{-1}(U_i))= ker (R_i\rightarrow ~\mathcal{O}_Y(\varphi_Y^{-1}(U_i))$, then we have $X\cong Y$?

Comment: second sentence*

Comment: Yes, but note what I'm proving is stronger - I'm showing that the quasicoherent ideal sheaves cutting out $X$ and $Y$ are the same. To show that these sheaves are the same, it suffices to show that they are the same on an open affine cover. Once we are in the affine setting, then it's enough to show that their global sections are the same, since quasicoherent sheaves on affines are determined by their global sections.

Comment: is this just the same as saying $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic *over $Z$*?  (at this point in the notes Vakil hasn't really developed quasicoherent ideal sheaves, so that may be why my questions may seem odd)

Comment: No, it's stronger: the isomorphism is the identity. You don't need much theory for this and indeed it should probably be developed in the section on closed immersions which from looking at the table of contents immediately precedes section where this exercise is found.

Comment: Yes i see now. there is a unique isomorphism $X\cong Y$ over Z. thank you

Comment: What is I tilde here?

Comment: @JohnnyApple The quasi-coherent sheaf on $\operatorname{Proj} S$ associated to the graded $S$-module $I$. This is a standard construction - see for instance [Stacks 01M&](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01M7).

Comment: Can you explain why $\mathcal I_X D(x_i)$ is the same as $(J_i)_{(x_i)}$?

Comment: @JohnnyApple This is just the definitions. $\mathcal{I}_X(D(x_i))= I_i$, and $J_i$ is spanned by the homogeneous elements of $S$ so that when you divide by the appropriate power of $x_i$, you end up in $I_i$. But this is exactly what the homogeneous localization does.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same $I$! Our definition is probably correct because that could be why Vakil says that generation in degree $1$ can be easier for some people, and we use this in our definition of $I$. I think now we are done because $\text{Proj}(S/I)$ and $X$ have the same data in terms of ideal sheaf. This is probably why several sources uses quasi-coherence. In fact, I believe Vakil is talking about this in 8.1.H. That is, affine-locally the two schemes $\text{Proj}(S/I)$ and $X$ have the same data, and their gluing are exactly the same. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score -3):

Hints: 1) Closed immersions are projective. 2) The composition of projective morphisms is projective (Segre-embedding). 3) Surjectivity of a homomorphism of graded rings can be tested locally.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't the first one is what I need to show?

Comment: No. 1) means that for every quasi-coherent ideal $I$ of a scheme $X$ there is some graded quasi-coherent algebra (insert finiteness conditions if necessary) $A$ on $X$ such that $V(I) = \mathrm{Proj}(A)$ as $X$-schemes. I think $A=\mathcal{O}_X/I$ concentrated in degree $0$ works.

Comment: Hey, do you guys know why we need finite generation of the graded ring? Don't we still get a homogeneous ideal $I$?

Comment: Dear Gil, we want to ideal sheaves to have the desired property $I(B)_f\cong I(B_f)$ so as to make sure it corresponds to a closed subscheme. In our case $I(B)_f=(\cap_i J_i(B))_f$, we need the finite generation because localization only commutes with finite intersections.

Comment: Is the result true if S is not finitely generated (by elements of degree 1)?