# Why $D_+(f)\cap V_+(I)$ in projective space is affine open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

This is a question about proposition 3.36 in Qing Liu's book.

Proposition 3.36(b) Let $X$ be a quasi-projective scheme over $A$ and $F$ a finite set of points of $X$. Then $F$ is contained in an affine open subset of $X$.

I understand every steps except for the last sentence. Why $D_+(f)\cap \hat{X}$ is an affine open set of $X$? Is this something really trivial to see?

I'm also wondering if it is true that any closed subscheme of $\mathbb P_A^n$ has a canonical strucure $\operatorname{Proj}(A[T_0,\dots,T_n]/I)$?

[image]

Comment: Sorry for asking so many stupid questions these days. But Qing's book drives me crazy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D_+(f)\cap \widehat{X}$ is a closed subset of $D_+(f)$ and an open subset of $X$. Since $D_+(f)$ is affine and closed subsets of affines are affine, $D_+(f)\cap \widehat{X}$ is affine. Since it's open in $X$, it's an affine open inside $X$.

As for your second question, every closed subscheme of $\operatorname{Proj} R$ [is indeed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059367/closed-subscheme-of-a-projective-scheme-determined-by-homogeneous-ideals) $\operatorname{Proj} R/I$ for some graded ideal $I$. This isn't unique without extra conditions, though: one needs to require that $I$ be saturated to get uniqueness. This is covered in most books.

Comment: Thank you so much! If let $\iota:\hat{X}\rightarrow \mathbb P_A^n$ be the closed immersion, then $D_+(f)\cap \hat{X} = \iota^{-1}(D_+(f))$ is automatically affine open. And it seems to be trivially true for any closed immersion. Why didn't I notice this before...

Comment: Yes, you've discovered that closed immersions [are](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01SE) [affine morphisms](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01S6).